# Magento 2 update default customer address data programmatically

Tags: magento2, address

I want to update customer default billing address and I tried following code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$address = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\Address')->load($customerData->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getEntityId());
$address->setCustomerId($customerId);
$address->setPostcode('452009');
$address->setId($customerData->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getEntityId());
$address->save();
```

Can anyone please help?